# How much does minifying reduce file size?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, minify, bundling-and-minification

In a React app, is it possible to find out how much Webpack's minification reduces the project's size **excluding all the dependencies and packages *not written* by the project's developer**?

My `build/static/` directory is currently bigger than my `src` directory and I believe it is because code from the dependencies is also minified with the files of interest. Where could I find something to approximately compare my `src` directory size to?

Comment: `and I believe it is because code from the dependencies is also minified` no, it's because code from dependencies is also included in the bundle. So it's not clear what you mean by "excluding all the dependencies ...". You can try comparing the size of your bundle with minification turned on and off. Or try webpack's code splitting to have your own code in separate bundle and see how much space that takes

Comment: While it doesn't directly answer your question, there are tools like [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to analyze your build bundles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built the project with `npm run build` to find out how large the output is with minimization enabled.

Then I edited `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js` and changed line 189 (the line with the `minimize` property) from:

```
...
    optimization: {
      minimize: isEnvProduction,
      minimizer: [
...
```

to:

```
...
    optimization: {
      minimize: false,
      minimizer: [
...
```

to disable minimization.

Then built the project again to find out its size without minimization.

You can compare the built file sizes manually to find out their difference, but you will also get a nice output to the terminal when building the second time:

```
File sizes after gzip:

  613.36 KB (+504.48 KB)  build\static\js\2.0ddf8239.chunk.js
  60.24 KB (+20.01 KB)    build\static\js\main.8e9dd59c.chunk.js
  4.73 KB (+457 B)        build\static\css\main.aaaa4d7d.chunk.css
  1.66 KB (+933 B)        build\static\js\runtime~main.7f8cc4df.js
```

Notice the differences stated in parantheses.